# Extra toggle buttons added when adding it dynamically

Tags: android

I am trying to add radio buttons dynamically.

What i have in my project :-

One Activity and 3 classes extending ToggleButtons :-

Left, Right , and Middle toggle buttons are there classes which is inflating three different xmls containing toggle buttons with rounded corners as per the name of the class. For example :-

xml and code for LeftToggleButton class :-

```
package com.example.radiobuttons;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LeftToggleButton extends ToggleButton{

    public LeftToggleButton(Context context, LinearLayout linearLayout) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.toggle_left_button, linearLayout);
    }

}
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ToggleButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector_left"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="@string/hello_world"
    android:textOn="@string/hello_world" />
```

Similarly, are the rest two classes.

In Main Activity, i am running a loop to add buttons :-

```
    LinearLayout mainLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        if(i == 0){
            LeftToggleButton leftButton = new LeftToggleButton(this, mainLinear);
            mainLinear.addView(leftButton);
        }
        else if(i == 1){
            RightToggleButton rightButton = new RightToggleButton(this, mainLinear);
            mainLinear.addView(rightButton);
        }
        else{
            MiddleToggleButton middleButton = new MiddleToggleButton(this, mainLinear);
            mainLinear.addView(middleButton);
        }
    }
```

The expected result should be this :-
[image]

But i am getting this result, a toggle button is coming extra after my customised button :-
[image]

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here. Why is that extra toggle button coming ?

Comment: try by delete your else if part..i.e only use if and else part..coz here middlebutton will never come through this logic.just check what happens..

Comment: What method are you running this loop in? `onCreate`?

Comment: otherwise do like i<3 in for loop .

Comment: ya its ok..the loop can be for more than 2 also. I need all the three buttons

Comment: so... whats the output after changing..

Comment: See the second image. For every custom toggleimage, another toggle button is also coming. The view should be like the first image

Comment: i think the problem is your constructor.  you use mainLinear two times. when each class constructure called it holds(through inflater) one togglebotton and in your loop you add another one in this same layout by addview.

Comment: you can use two different layouts or delete the layout from constructure and put it like null or something.

Comment: If i put null, then it is not added